# exception during cache and session cleaning magento 1.9.3

Tags: cache, session, exception, magento1.9.3

I'm trying to install Magento 1.9 and I got this error , how can I solved it,

[image]

Comment: click on refresh

Comment: Could you provide the full log content and not just a screenshot of the last few lines? Chances are that somewhere up the lines something went wrong. There is no telling what might be the issue now.

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

Go to downloader/Maged/Connect.php, find

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.JSONeval(true) || {};
```

replace it with:

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || JSON.parse(transport.responseText) || {};
```

This works for me when i try to install extension with "Exception during cache and session cleaning" message. Hope, this solution will help you.